# Google Apps Script: How to handle responses of a Form that was dynamically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have written a simple Apps Script, which does the following:

- Creates a Google Form, and populates it's fields accordingly with validation.
- Creates a Folder and uploads it onto Google Drive.
- Creates a Spreadsheet File and uploads it into the Folder created above.

What I want to do now is handle Google Form submission using the script to send email responses. How would I go about handling Google Form submissions without having to manually attach another script every time I create a form using the above mentioned script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to use the onFormSubmit trigger.
Specifies a trigger that will fire when a response is submitted to the form.

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
  .forForm(form)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
```

Read the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()).